# I want to to charge a capacitor with rectified mains voltage BUT

Tags: capacitor, diodes, mains

But when I make the connections the house fuse just blows.Capacitor values is 3000uF 450v. When I measure the voltages of the rectified (bridge) mains, I get a reading of 207VDC and 80VAC
(ı think its the unfiltered bumps, but not sure)
But then I tried 1000uf 450v and fuse didnt blow. How can I charge a cap with mains? Can anyone help? Thx

Comment: Add a series resistor to limit the peak current.

Comment: Please try not to kill yourself or someone near you. 1000's of uF charged up to 100's of V is a lot of energy.

Comment: Don't. This is too dangerous for someone asking this question

Answer (score 4):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAgZdS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Series mains lamp.*

> But when I make the connections the house fuse just blows.

This probably means that you did this without a circuit fuse. This is foolish. You should include a fuse rated to limit the current to a safe value.

While we're on the subject, fuse discrimination is a topic you can read up on to learn how to size fuses properly so that the fuse closest to the load blows without blowing or tripping upstream protection devices which would affect other devices on that circuit.

> Capacitor values is 3000 uF 450 V.

A discharged capacitor will act as a short circuit when initially connected to the supply. Apart from tripping your fuse / circuit breaker it could also destroy the bridge rectifier.

> How can I charge a cap with mains?

Add a mains rated bulb in series. You may see an initial flash and fade out as the capacitor charges up. You can also use it to discharge the capacitor safely.

---

Safety: there is enough energy in this circuit to kill. All should be enclosed in an insulated case or in an earthed metal case.